# How to prevent background image from tiling?

Tags: html, css

```
<div style="background-image: url('https://i.ibb.co/v1B855w/bg15.png'); color: #000000; background-color: #000000; background-attachment: fixed; text-align: center;"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/L6zQY0S/name6.png" /></div>
```

I wish to make the background image display the entire width instead of tiling.

tried stretching the background to 100%, it didnt work

Comment: `background-repeat:no-repeat;` is for "not tiling", `background-size: cover` makes sure the image is filling the whole element without being distorted in proportion.

Answer (score 2):

```css
.bg {
  background-image: url('https://i.ibb.co/v1B855w/bg15.png');
  color: #000000;
  background-size:cover;
  background-color: #000000;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  text-align: center;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="bg">
  <img src="https://i.ibb.co/L6zQY0S/name6.png" /> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `background-size:100% 100%;` value for stretching your background image fully.

```css
.bg {
  background-image: url('https://i.ibb.co/v1B855w/bg15.png');
  color: #000000;
  background-size:100% 100%;
  background-color: #000000;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  text-align: center;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="bg">
    <img src="https://i.ibb.co/L6zQY0S/name6.png" /> 
  </div>
```

Comment: Neither of these work. The desired effect  is that the background stays static while the name is dynamic. in both "answers" given those action work, but the same problem persists.